# Are clauses like 'ORDER BY' and 'GROUP BY' vulnerable to injection in SQLite?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

My app using Node.js and SQLite needs query my db dynamically using user input, including in the 'GROUP BY' and 'ORDER BY' clauses.  How can I make these queries safe against injection?  I've heard a little about parameterized queries, but as far as I can tell I can't use them with the clauses I mention above because they take column names rather than values.  Here's an example of one of my queries, where the 'GROUP BY' clause is dependent on user input:

```
async getYearlyStats(table, id) {
        try {
            const result = await this.db.all(`
                SELECT
                    CAST(year AS INTEGER) AS year,
                    COUNT(*) AS count
                FROM
                    (
                SELECT
                    cops.*,
                    strftime('%Y', complaints.date_received) AS year
                FROM
                    cops
                INNER JOIN
                    allegations
                ON 
                    allegations.cop = cops.id
                INNER JOIN
                    complaints
                ON
                    complaints.id = allegations.complaint_id
                WHERE 
                    cops.id = '${id}'
                GROUP BY
                    ${table}.id
                )
                GROUP BY
                    year
            `)
            return result
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    }
```

It is possible that the value for 'GROUP BY' could include an underscore, e.g. 'num_allegations'

Comment: To be robust, you'd want to wrap the table name in double quotes (And double up any double quotes in the name (Though anyone who uses a table name like that should be hung up by their thumbs)).

Comment: And the value in the where clause should be a bound parameter, not included directly in the query like that.

Comment: @Shawn could you give me an example of what you're talking about with the double quotes, and doubling up on them?

Comment: I guess my confusion is: are you saying that the 'GROUP BY' clause should read as:

````
GROUP BY
    "parameter".id
?

The issue with that is: how do I access a property like I'm doing here?  (The .id parameter)

Comment: Yes, like that. Double quotes are used to mark identifiers like table and column names so that they can have things like whitespace, punctuation, or the same name as a sql keyword (Though all that is bad practice IMO, it's allowed). So you'd want `"${table}".id` instead of just `${table}.id` to help protect against such problematic names. (And if the contents of the `table` variable has double quotes, they should be replaced by two double quotes each to escape them)

Comment: I see.  Thanks a lot for the helpful answers.  I guess this goes without saying, but the double quotes also protect against injection?  Sorry if I'm making you repeat yourself, I'm just really trying to get a grasp on how to better secure my queries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227903/discussion-between-leaozinho-and-shawn).